# Swift Generics, Stucts and Protocol: No accessible initializers

Tags: generics, struct, protocols, swift2, xcode7

why doesn't this code compile?

The compilation error is in the struct FirmDecoder "return Firm()".

The error message is: 'Firm' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit
protocol EntityDecoder {
  func decode<U>(json: [String:AnyObject], index: Int) -> U
}

public struct Firm {
  public init(){}
}

struct FirmDecoder : EntityDecoder {
  func decode<Firm>(json: [String : AnyObject], index: Int) -> Firm {
    return Firm()
  }
}

//extension EntityDecoder {
// func decode<Firm>(json: [String : AnyObject], index: Int) -> Firm {
// return Firm()
// }
//}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6bAE.png

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
@JeremyP @mixel I didn't mean to declare FirmDecoder.decode() as a generic function. So your "orginal answer" was what I was trying to achieve.

Am I right thinking that instead of having to implement .decode for FirmDecoder, I could make an extension protocol to provide a default implementation, so FirmDecoder would just need to implement the HasInitializer you proposed in your updated answer.

Something like (I don't have access to XCode currently):

```
protocol HasJsonInitializer {
    init(json: [String:AnyObject], index: Int)
}

protocol EntityDecoder {
    func decode<U: HasJsonInitializer>(json: [String:AnyObject], index: Int) -> U
}

extension EntityDecoder {
    func decode<U: HasJsonInitializer>(json: [String : AnyObject], index: Int) -> U {
        return U(json, index: index)
    }
}

struct FirmDecoder : EntityDecoder, HasJsonInitializer {
    init(json: [String:AnyObject], index: Int) {
        // json processing
    }
}
```

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you want do keep `decode<U>` as generic function then you should add a constraint to generic parameter `U` that says that `U` must have initializer with no parameters:

```
protocol HasInitializer {
    init()
}

protocol EntityDecoder {
    func decode<U: HasInitializer>(json: [String:AnyObject], index: Int) -> U
}

struct FirmDecoder : EntityDecoder {
    func decode<Firm: HasInitializer>(json: [String : AnyObject], index: Int) -> Firm {
        return Firm()
    }
}
```

And do not use same name `Firm` for generic parameter and struct. It's confusing.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You `EntityDecoder` and `FirmDecoder` definition is invalid, that's the right way:

```
import UIKit
protocol EntityDecoder {
    typealias U
    func decode(json: [String:AnyObject], index: Int) -> U
}

public struct Firm {
    public init() {}
}

struct FirmDecoder : EntityDecoder {
    func decode(json: [String : AnyObject], index: Int) -> Firm {
        return Firm()
    }
}
```

Comment: To add a bit of explanation, in the question: `decode<Firm>` declares a generic function and "Firm" here is used as a placeholder for any type instead of the actual `struct Firm`

Comment: @JeremyP I updated my answer but I do not understand why you made `FirmDecoder.decode()` method generic and why are you expecting that `Firm` generic parameter will have initializer with no parameters.

Comment: @Eternam Sorry I confused you with JeremyP :) If everything is alright please accept my answer.